# How to avoid SSL in image resize?

Tags: magento2.2

I want to resize the image. Below is my code

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $blogCollection = json_decode($result, true);
```

It is throwing the below error:

> Warning: getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
>   Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL
>   routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in
>   /var/www/html/magento226/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Image/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php
>   on line 304.

How to fix this

Comment: Try with `$ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, NULL`

Comment: Its also not working

Comment: Try to look what code sits around line 304 in file `/var/www/html/magento226/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Image/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php` - whether CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is set to false or not